# Getting key:value pairs from Shopify Graphql query response using Node js

Tags: node.js, graphql, shopify

Here is my Graphql query

```
      const gqlQuery = `query ($lastCursor: String) {
    products(first:100, after: $lastCursor) {
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        hasPreviousPage
      }
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        variants(first:2) {
          edges {
            node {
              sku
              inventoryQuantity
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Im calling it in a do/while hasNextPage = true loop to get back a couple of key:value pairs for every product in a Shopify store

```
  const data = await shopifyGraphqlClient.graphql(gqlQuery, variable);
```

The results look like this when i dump them to the browser using res.send:

```
    undefined{"products":{"pageInfo":{"hasNextPage":true,"hasPreviousPage":false},"edges":[{"cursor":"eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo3NTk4MjYxMTMsImxhc3RfdmFsdWUiOiI3NTk4MjYxMTMifQ==","node":{"variants":{"edges":[{"node":{"sku":"isa-asl-26x22","inventoryQuantity":10}}]}}},{"cursor":"eyJsYXN0X2lkIjoxMDU0MDQ5MTUzLCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiMTA1NDA0OTE1MyJ9","node":{"variants":{"edges":[{"node":{"sku":"Sien-asl-73x49","inventoryQuantity":11}}]}}},{"cursor":"eyJsYXN0X2lkIjoxMDU0MjA3NDg5LCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiMTA1NDIwNzQ4OSJ9","node":{"variants":{"edges":[{"node":{"sku":"Sien-vwh-73x49","inventoryQuantity":11}}]}}},{"cursor":"eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo0MDc0NzkwMzQzLCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiNDA3NDc5MDM0MyJ9","node":{"variants":{"edges":[{"node":{"sku":"ren-dwh-36","inventoryQuantity":4}}]}}},{"cursor":"eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo0MDg5ODM1ODQ3LCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiNDA4OTgzNTg0NyJ9","node":{"variants":{"edges":[{"node":{"sku":"ara-dwh-56x32","inventoryQuantity":7}}]}}},{"cursor":"eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo0MDg5ODg3NTU5LCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiNDA4OTg4NzU1OSJ9","node":{"variants":{"edges":[{"node":{"sku":"Pro-dwh-32x24","inventoryQuantity":23}}]}}},{"cursor":"eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo0MDg5ODk1MTc1LCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiNDA4OTg5NTE3NSJ9","node":{"variants":{"edges":[{"node":{"sku":"Pro-dwh-40x28","inventoryQuantity":7}}]}}}...
```

and so on.

I just want the "sku" and "inventoryQuantity" fields, how can I isolate them into a JSON format file, and while I'm asking, any idea where the "undefined" is coming from?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Bulk Query to get all products. Check that feature out. The bonus is, you get the data in JSON. So save yourself the headaches of the cursor-based approach, and just download inventory in bulk.

Comment: I've read up on the bulk operation approach but I'm a noob to Graphql and not very experienced with Node/JavaScript.

The results I've got using pagination took me nearly 2 weeks to figure out, the bulk approach is so confusing and I can't find anything in the way of coding examples or tutorials to follow. I'm kind of loathe to set aside the hard work I've already done and start struggling again. Thanks anyway, I'm grateful for the input.

Comment: Keep at it. The Bulk Download is much easier than your approach. You're wasting zero effort switching, as your method is definitely as hard as it gets, and won't get easier. In fact, to make your approach work, you probably have many weeks of pain ahead!

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement, I had a feeling you would say that! OK I'll give it a go with the bulk operations approach, do you know of any code examples or tutorials that might point me along the right path? The Shopify API documentation is frustratingly sketchy for a newcomer.

Comment: I don't bother with Javascript for my work, I use Ruby, so that won't help you out. I am sure there are plenty of JS'ers out there though that can help you. Try the forums. They have some people using JS these days.